# Hebrew characters doesn't shown correctly

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, phpmyadmin, hebrew

I have a PHP script that takes data from MySQL database and write it with echo, the problem is that it shows Hebrew as just a weird string and not the actual content, on the phpMyAdmin database it shows the Hebrew characters fine and it is encoded there to `utf8_general_ci`, but when it transferred to the PHP it doesn't work.

On the PHP code I tried to encode is:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
?>
```

but it didn't work, the PHP code is:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db);

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($response,array($row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5],$row[6]));
}
$str = json_encode(array($response));
$str = clean($str);
echo $str;
mysqli_close($conn);

function clean($string) {
    $string = str_replace(' ', ' ', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9,: -]/', '', $string);
    return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string);
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of the actual output?

Comment: Set the charset of your DB object, `mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");` after creating the connection.